# Embedded YouTube Video doesn't load

Tags: html, video, youtube, embed

I have embedded video from youtube plenty of times before, but for some reason I have been failing at it for the past few days. I tried different videos, and I also built an empty .html dedicated to getting an embedded video to show, but nothing worked. I am using the embed button from youtube. I tried with the old embed code and the new  one, and it still wont show the video. The most I get is an empty white box. I'm using FF, IE, and chrome. Total failure. Heres what ive reduced it to:

```
<html>
<p>hello world</p>
<object width="560" height="315">
 <param name="movie" value="//www.youtube.com/v/P1LNiD88690?hl=en_US&amp;version=3&amp;rel=0"></param>
 <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
 <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
   <embed src="//www.youtube.com/v/P1LNiD88690?hl=en_US&amp;version=3&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="560" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" 
allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
</object>
</html>
```

This doesnt work nor does the  version. I also tried this on another computer and it still didnt work. What am I missing??

Comment: Your coding seems working fine. May be do you have any firewall to block the website ? Or You copy and paste the video url in browser and check it is working or not? Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DPfMW/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the HTML into a JSFiddle, and it seems to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/g7R6g/

Maybe it is the editing that `user876345` did to your post that makes it work.

Is there another way to reproduce the error?

Comment: Thanks, its working in JSFiddle, but when I use the SAME html cut and pasted is not working. I get no error, just a blank spot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Im using notepad now just to make sure theres no interference. It looks like this: http://imgur.com/ZrkjcAC

Comment: Ah, the problem is the "//" at the beginning of the two YouTube URLs. If you replace it with an "http://", it should work. The reason why is because "//" is a "scheme-relative URL" which means it will try the "file:" scheme instead of the "http:" scheme. And "file://youtube.com" doesn't exist!

Comment: OMFG, that worked. Wtf!! Wonder why it automatically worked in JSfiddle. Thanks so much!

Comment: :). It worked in JSFiddle because the scheme-relative URL was relative to "http:" (the scheme is "http") and so it was trying to load `"http://youtube.com"`, which worked!